# x.addEventListener is not a function?

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I was working on a small project to prepare my self for exam
i've some kinda of tables and i've to change the color of each one randomly to red or green and some other stuff,
but my problem is that the colors wont show even after I press the "start" button.

Could you please take a look at my code and tell me whats wrong with it? and if there is any suggestion to help me improve my code writing ?

The code keep on saying something like button.addeventlistener is not a function.

I looked around the forum and most of them where talking about changing the placement of the script, doing that didn't helped. I even wrote the entire script in the index file.. that didn't changed anything as well
Thank you

Code:

Given the following HTML/CSS code that draws a table of 20 buttons, in addition to an action “Start” button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      button:not(#start) {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
      }
      #start {
        font-size: 40px;
        width: 310px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 105px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
        <td><button></button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <button id="start">
      START
    </button>
<script>var rand;
  // Math.floor((Math.random()*1)+1);
  //question 1
  var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  var td =document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  var btn =document.getElementById('start');
  btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      console.log("ali");
      for(var i=0 ;i< button.length;i++){
      rand=  Math.floor((Math.random()*2));
      console.log(rand);
      if(rand==1){
          button[i].style.backgroundcolor="red";
          console.log("red")
      }
      else if(rand==0){
      button[i].style.backgroundcolor="green";
  console.log("green")
  }
      }})
  //question 2

  button.addEventListener('click',function(e){

  if(button.target.style.backgroundcolor=="red")
  button.target.style.backgroundcolor=="";




  })

  //question 3

  for (var i=0;i<button.length;i++){
  if(button[i].style.backgroundcolor!="green")
  i--;

  if(i==button.length){
  alert("You Won");
  //question 4
  for (var i=0;i<button.length;i++){
  button[i].style.backgroundcolor=="";


  }


  }
  }

  //question 5

  btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  button[i].style.backgroundcolor=="";






  })

   </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's `addEventListener` not `addeventListener`

Comment: `button` is a `NodeList` (a list of *multiple* elements), so you need to loop over it and add the event listener to each button separately. I recommend you to choose a less confusing name for your variable.

Comment: @CodeManiac I didn't capitalize while writing the post or the title as well. but its written correctly in the code

Comment: @TiiJ7 wouldnt the x.target fix this problem ? if not can you please clarify the use of it?

Comment: also, what's the difference between a node and an array?

Comment: @AliZgheib an array is a JS collection of things. A `NodeList` is a DOM collection of things. It's not an array but it's what is called an "array-like" - it has numerical indexes and a `length` property but it doesn't have the methods belonging to a normal JS array, like `.map()` or `.find()`, etc.

Comment: Your homework directions say: *"...that draws a table of 20 buttons, in addition to an action “Start” button:"* Are you expected to dynamically create the table and/or buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection of elements as opposed to a single element so you would have to iterate over them. Example:

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); // get the buttons
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) { // loop over them
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // your event code here
  }); // add event listener to each one
}
```

Note that this will also apply the event listener to the `Start` button (since it is also a button), so if you wish to prevent that, you would add an `id` attribute to the root `<table>` element (example: `<table id="button_table">`) and use 
`Element.getElementsByTagName()` like so:

```js
var button_table = document.getElementById('button_table');
var buttons = button_table.getElementsByTagName('button');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');`

the result is a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (array like)

To add an eventlistener to the targets you have to loop through them.

1. make a real array from the HTMLCollection
2. loop through it and add an eventlistener to the target elements.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

Array.from(button).forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     console.log(this);
  });
});
```